# For which values of $\lambda$ is $M$ a regular surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm working on a problem that asks for the values of $\lambda$ such that

$$ M_{\lambda} = \{(x,y,x)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+2x-4yz=z^2+\lambda \} $$

is a regular surface. To do this I set $f(x,y,z)=x^2+2x-4yz-z^2 - \lambda$ and worked out that $(f_x,f_y,f_z)= (2x+2, -4z, -4y-2z)$ which equals $0$ at $(-1,0,0)$. I don't really understand where to go from here.

Is it possible to do this part of the question in a different way as well?

The second part of the question asks for a local parametrization of a neighbourhood of $p=(1,0,-\sqrt3) \in M_0.$ I don't really see how to do this so any advice for this part is appreciated.

Comment: For which values of $\lambda$ the point with a possible singularity that you computed is on the surface? If it is not, the surface will be regular.

Comment: @Matthias so if I understand correctly the surface is regular for all $\lambda \neq -1$?

Comment: One would rather not guess at what arithmetic calculation you might have done to arrive at the inequality $\lambda \ne -1$. Perhaps you could instead express that more conceptually as an inequality regarding the function $f$.

Comment: You might even be in position to answer your own question (ignoring the "second part" and keeping in mind that one this site one should [ask one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671)).